# Toolstripcontrolhost with Toolstripsplitbutton- remove blank spaces

Tags: c#, winforms

I have recently started using winForms and I am trying to use a panel as a dropdown with ToolStripSplitButton. I wrote a usercontrol (customToolStrip) the inherits toolStrip class and have an extra method as in the code below.

```
public void AddPanelToSplitButton (Panel panel, ToolStripSplitButton button)
{


    ToolStripControlHost tcHost = new ToolStripControlHost(panel);
    tcHost.Margin = Padding.Empty;
    tcHost.Padding = Padding.Empty;
    tcHost.AutoSize = false;
    tcHost.Size = panel.Size;


    button.DropDown.Size = tcHost.Size;
    button.DropDown.Margin = Padding.Empty;
    button.DropDown.Padding = Padding.Empty;
    button.DropDown.Items.Add(tcHost);
    button.ShowDropDown();
    button.HideDropDown();


}
```

[image]

Could someone please guide me how to remove this white space on either side of the panel.

My requirement is something like this: without white spaces.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
public void AddPanelToSplitButton (Panel panel, ToolStripSplitButton button)
{

ToolStripControlHost tcHost = new ToolStripControlHost(panel);
tcHost.Margin = Padding.Empty;
tcHost.Padding = Padding.Empty;
tcHost.AutoSize = false;
tcHost.Size = panel.Size;

ToolStripDropDown dropDown = new ToolStripDropDown();
dropDown.Items.Add(tcHost);
button.DropDown = dropDown;


}
```